# How to fix cannot resolve layout inflated in View?

Tags: java, android, layout

I got this error:

`Cannot resolve symbol 'list_sirah'`

It is a layout that I inflated it to my View using LayoutInflater. Maybe there is another way to inflate it to my View?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItem = convertView;
    if(listItem == null){
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_sirah,parent,false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the xml of that layout?

Comment: check your layout name and use layout name

Comment: Rebuild the project. Android Studio does not recognize new files instantly in some cases.